# Youtube iframe embed thumbnail squashed in IE with player size 640x360 or larger

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, youtube-api, thumbnails

I've run into a problem with the Youtube API iframe embed in Internet Explorer.  I want to have the video embeded with showinfo=0 and controls=2 so that it displays the video thumbnail without the title bar and control bar before click to play.  Afterwards the controls only display on mouseover.

This works fine in all browsers... except in IE... only if the player is 640x360 or larger the thumbnail becomes squashed with black bars above and below it.  Curiously, if the player size is 350x197 or 560x315 this does not happen.

Anyone have an idea what is the problem?

I've prepared a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/d8s3g/2/

Here is the youtube iframe embed code I am using:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_LmAcfO9lyg?showinfo=0&controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a combination of Youtube API iframe parameters which work it IE at all sizes.  showinfo=0 & autohide=1" (removed controls=2)

This youtube iframe embed code does the trick:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_LmAcfO9lyg?fs=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```